# Custom Category Gallery with masonry

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-masonry, masonry

I'm little bit lost, I want build a menu which made from post which have category "gallery" which displaying gallery on each post with masonry with the effect easeInOutQuad after fade in and fade out. the fade in and the fade out effect seems working, but the masonry itself didn't reconstruct or reload seems like broken

Here is my code

```
<!-- this is for menu, I'm querying post which have category gallery-->
<div class="gallery-menu">
<?php 
$category = get_term_by('slug', 'gallery', 'category');
            $args = array(
            'category'        => $category->term_id,
            'orderby'         => 'post_date',
            'order'           => 'DESC',
            'post_type'       => 'post',
            'post_status'     => 'publish'
            );
            $test = get_posts( $args );
        ?>
        <ul id="gallery-menu">
            <?php 
            foreach($test as $post) {?>
                <li id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>">
                    <a href="#"><?php echo $post->post_title; ?></a>
                </li>
            <?php } ?>
        </ul>
</div>

<!-- displaying gallery image on that post using advance custom field
 the masonry class for content is "gallery-content" and the list is class "item" -->
<div class="galls" id="gallery-content">
    <?php foreach($test as $post) {?>
        <div id="<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" class="content">
            <ul class="gallery-content">
            <?php while ( have_rows('gallery_content') ) : the_row(); ?>
                <li class="item">
                    <?php
                    $gallerylink = get_sub_field('gallery_picture'); 
                    ?>
                    <img src="<?php echo $gallerylink; ?>">
                </li>
            <?php endwhile; ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>


<!-- my javascript for displaying on click and for masonry -->
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#gallery-content').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.item',
          isFitWidth: true,
          isAnimated: true,
          animationOptions: {
            duration: 750,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
          },
          isAnimated: !Modernizr.csstransitions 
        });

    jQuery('#gallery-menu li a').click(function(e){

        hideContentDivs();
        var tmp_div = jQuery(this).parent().index();
            jQuery('.galls .content').eq(tmp_div).fadeIn();

     });
    function hideContentDivs(){
        jQuery('.galls .content').each(function(){
            jQuery(this).fadeOut();

        })
    }
});
</script>
```

After all I'm trying to use:

```
$('#gallery-content').masonry('reloadItems');
$('#gallery-content').masonry('reload');
```

but seems everything not working, images loaded but not in good location (at the same location), images not loaded, or everything broken.

What my purpose is when I click the menu on gallery the gallery is reloaded on masonry which have easeinOutQuad effect

Like this website example: http://pawonpasundan.com/our-menus/

I need help :(

Comment: missing # inside selector?? $('#gallery-content')

Comment: thanks mate, i'm already added the # but still not working, or do you know where i should put that code ?

Comment: i guess you need to bind the click event to sort the items

Comment: how mate? do you have example?